# Swift GoogleMaps fitBounds Zoom

Tags: swift, google-maps, zooming, markers, fitbounds

New coder try to fit GoogleMap in my view.

I have searched a lot of information and I have come to this conclusion, but it does not work for me.

override func loadView() {

```
    var markerList = [GMSMarker]()

    // Create a GMSCameraPosition
    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 4.390205, longitude: 2.154007, zoom: 8)
    let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
    mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
    view = mapView

    mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true
    //mapView.setMinZoom(10, maxZoom: 20)

    //create markers
    for loc in arrayOfMapStops {
        let marker = GMSMarker()
        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: loc.lat, longitude: loc.long)
        marker.title = loc.address
        marker.snippet = loc.type
        if loc.type == "Entrega" {marker.icon = GMSMarker.markerImage(with: .green)}
        else {marker.icon = GMSMarker.markerImage(with: .blue)}
        marker.map = mapView
        markerList.append(marker)
    }

    //fit map to markers
    var bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds()
    for marker in markerList {
        bounds = bounds.includingCoordinate(marker.position)
    }
    let update = GMSCameraUpdate.fit(bounds)
    mapView.moveCamera(update)
}
```

The map is not adjusted with the proper zoom.

[image: image of situation]

Anyone can help me with the zoom issue?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: thanks for suggest @Nrzonline!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved the problem by myself. I use DispatchQueue to set the right zoom to my map.

Here is my final code:

```
override func loadView() {

    var markerList = [GMSMarker]()

    // Create a GMSCameraPosition
    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 40.4167 , longitude: -3.70325, zoom: 8)
    let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
    mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
    view = mapView

    mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true
    //mapView.setMinZoom(10, maxZoom: 20)

    //create markers
    for loc in arrayOfMapStops {
        let marker = GMSMarker()
        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: loc.lat, longitude: loc.long)
        marker.title = loc.address
        marker.snippet = loc.type
        if loc.type == "Entrega" {marker.icon = GMSMarker.markerImage(with: .green)}
        else {marker.icon = GMSMarker.markerImage(with: .blue)}
        marker.map = mapView
        markerList.append(marker)
    }

    delay(seconds: 3) { () -> () in
        //fit map to markers
        var bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds()
        for marker in markerList {
            bounds = bounds.includingCoordinate(marker.position)
        }
        let update = GMSCameraUpdate.fit(bounds, withPadding: 100.0)
        mapView.animate(with: update)
    }
}

func delay(seconds: Double, completion:@escaping ()->()) {
    let when = DispatchTime.now() + seconds
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when) {
        completion()
    }
}
```

:)

Comment: didn't work to me, i'm still facing the same issue, anyone can help?

Comment: @ANeme did you use the DispatchQueue?? For me, worked like charm.

Comment: I found what was wrong, you'r dispatchQueue thing helped the animation to work as expected, but my problem was each time you need to include coordinate you have to assign it back to bounds :) this was the problem

Comment: @RaulF. did you figure out the root cause of the problem?

Comment: The same issue faced, and tried to solve but no luck, can not understand with the issue, the same app in android working fine, my android developer friend simple use the animate camera like here we use

Answer (score 0):

Please follow these below code

```
if self.allSelectedActiveMarkers.count > 0 {
               let firstLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: self.allSelectedActiveMarkers.first?.currentLat ?? 0.0, longitude: self.allSelectedActiveMarkers.first?.currentLong ?? 0.0)
                 var bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(coordinate: firstLocation, coordinate: firstLocation)
                 for marker in self.allSelectedActiveMarkers {
                   bounds = bounds.includingCoordinate(marker.position)
                 }
                let update = GMSCameraUpdate.fit(bounds, withPadding: CGFloat(20))
                self.mapView.animate(with: update)
             }
```